# Scroll bar covering interaction element in WebKit on Mountain Lion

Tags: css, webkit, scrollbar, osx-mountain-lion

I have a tiny button floated to the right edge of its container, which has the style `overflow-y: scroll`. On Mac OS X Mountain Lion, in Safari and Chrome, on devices that have a trackpad and no mouse, this tiny button is covered up by Mountain Lion's new hidden scrollbars.

How can I detect when my tiny button is in this situation and/or ensure it is not covered by the scroll bar?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jP8rg/

A similar question with no answer: [CSS hover bug on Lion/Mountain Lion with hidden scrollbars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15649202/css-hover-bug-on-lion-mountain-lion-with-hidden-scrollbars)

Answer (score 1):

well, assuming you can't just put a little margin-right in there so the elements no longer overlap or tweak the design to avoid the issue altogether, you *could* style the scrollbar... well, in webkit-ish browsers at least.

here's a good overview --> http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/

having lived thru the early days of customized scrollbars, i personally would avoid if at all possible.

with a little work, you can also detect when scrollbars are present... sorta.

some options here --> [Scrollbar appear / disappear event in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578046/scrollbar-appear-disappear-event-in-jquery)

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to style the scrollbar with default style, but tell it not to overlap any of my dang document? Every pixel is sacred, but the defilers at Apple have forgotten.

Comment: hmmm... you could make it super-thin via --> ::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 1px; }

Comment: that makes the scroll bar disappear entirely - any change to ::-webkit-scrollbar causes the default style to disappear :(